# Changing the color of a bootstrap navbar on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there have been a lot of questions about this but none of the answers seem to be working for me. I am trying to write some jquery to make my bootstrap navbar change color once somebody has scrolled passed an element. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Github link: https://github.com/Sruthik22/Sruthik22.github.io the jquery is in the head

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sruthi Kurada</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sruthi Kurada's Personal Website">
        <meta name="author" content="Sruthi Kurada">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#Home');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
        $('nav.navbar-custom').css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
    } else {
        $('nav.navbar-custom').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
    }
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#Home">Sruthi Kurada</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <a class="navbar-brand nav-elements page-scroll" href="#Home">Home</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand nav-elements page-scroll" href="#About">About</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand nav-elements page-scroll" href="#Skills">Skills</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand nav-elements page-scroll" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        <a class="navbar-brand nav-elements page-scroll" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <a name = "Home" id = "Home"></a>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="Images/Robotics.jpg" alt="FLL Robotics Robot">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Innovator</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/Math.jpg" alt="Math on a chalkboard">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Math Enthusiast</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/PythonCode.png" alt="Python Code on Computer">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Coder</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--About Me-->
        <a name="About" id = "About"></a>
        <div class = "About">
            <div class="container">
                <br>
                <div id="sruthi-picture"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class = "col-md-1 col-xs-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 text-center" id="Intro">
                        My name is Sruthi Kurada
                    </div>
                    <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 text-center" id = "Subtitle">
                        I am a 7th Grader at the Advanced Math & Science Academy (AMSA).
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 text-center" id = "about-descript">
                        I am interested in Robotics, Math, and Coding. I participate in FLL a Lego Robotics Competition. I do many mathamatics competitions, and I have coded several Python and Java Projects.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 text-center" id = "about-descript">
                        I enjoy designing technology for less fortunate people and recently designed a belt to help the blind. I also play basketball & do karate as extracuriculars.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "AMSA">
            <div class="row">
                <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-10 text-center vcenter" id = "amsaText">
                    <p>My school the Advanced Math and Science Academy is where I participate in many activities with my friends.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a name="Skills"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h2 id = "SkillsTitle">Skills</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-users fa-stack-1x text-primary portfolioIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong class = "PortfolioTextTitle">Leadership</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <br>
                                <p class = "PortfolioText"> Taught people on my FLL team how to build robots. Also have taught kids how to code</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-android fa-stack-1x text-primary portfolioIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong class = "PortfolioTextTitle">App Developement</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <br>
                                <p class = "PortfolioText"> Learning Android Development and currently working on Udacity Nanodegree </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x text-primary portfolioIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong class = "PortfolioTextTitle">Python</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <br>
                                <p class = "PortfolioText"> Well versed in Python Application Development as well as Django Framework. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x text-primary portfolioIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <h4>
                                    <strong class = "PortfolioTextTitle">Java</strong>
                                </h4>
                                <br>
                                <p class = "PortfolioText"> Proficent in Java Developement. Currently learning Machine Learning.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a name="Portfolio"></a>
        <div class = "Portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                <div class = "col-md-1 col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 text-center" id="PortfolioTitle">
                    Portfolio                        
                </div>
                <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-0"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">                    
                    <div class = "portfolio-box">
                        <a title = "Movie App Github Source Code" href = "https://github.com/Sruthik22/MoviesApp">
                            <img class = "img-portfolio img-responsive" src = "Images/PopularMovies.PNG"/>
                            <p class = "imagetext">Movies App</p>
                            <div class = "portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class = "portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class = "project-category text-faded">
                                        Android Development
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "project-name">
                                        An Android app I created that lets users find most popular movies and the top rated movies. Once you click on a movie specific movie poster then it will give you more specific details such as movie title and release date.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class = "portfolio-box">
                        <a title = "Clash of the Math Titans Github Source Code" href = "https://github.com/Sruthik22/Clash-of-the-Math-Titans">
                            <img class = "img-portfolio img-responsive" src = "Images/ClashOfTheMathTitans.png" alt="Code of Clash of the Math Titans"/>
                            <p class = "imagetext">Clash of the Math Titans</p>
                            <div class = "portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class = "portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class = "project-category text-faded">
                                        Code
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "project-name">
                                        At a Hackathon my teammate and I designed this python game that helps young children learn the Order of Operations by gamifying it.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-0"></div>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-0"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class = "portfolio-box">
                        <a title = "Battleship Github Source Code" href = "#">
                            <img class = "img-portfolio img-responsive" src = "Images/Battleship.png" alt="The Battleship code"/>
                            <p class = "imagetext">Battleship</p>
                            <div class = "portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class = "portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class = "project-category text-faded">
                                        Code
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "project-name">
                                        The game battleship coded in python. There is both a single player mode and a multiplayer mode. The game also has graphics with the help of the graphics module graphics.py
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">                    
                    <div class = "portfolio-box">
                        <a title = "Movie App Github Source Code" href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogvRFzNWM2w">
                            <img class = "img-portfolio img-responsive" src = "Images/BeltForTheBlind.PNG" alt="Picture of the Limits of what a Product like the Blind Belt could do"/>
                            <p class = "imagetext">Belt for the Blind</p>
                            <div class = "portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class = "portfolio-box-caption-content">
                                    <div class = "project-category text-faded">
                                        Hardware
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "project-name">
                                        A product I designed along with another team mate that helps the blind traverse their surroundings. It guides the user by using a ultrasonic sensor and alerts the user by using a volume component on the side of the bot. We won 3rd place in ProjectCSGirls.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-2 col-sm-0"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>

        <a name="Contact"></a>
        <div class = "Contact">
            <div class="row">
                <div class = "col-md-1 col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 text-center">
                    <h1 id="ContactTitle">Contact</h1>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
                <div class = "col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <a target="_blank" href = "https://github.com/Sruthik22" class = "social"><i class="fa fa-github-square social"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 center col-sm-2">
                    <a target="_blank" href = "mailto:fllheroes638@gmail.com" class = "social"><i class="fa fa-envelope icon social"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <a target="_blank" href = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/5693112/sruthi-kurada" class = "social"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow social"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is in css query, query just `.navbar`

Answer (score 0):

You're simply targeting the wrong element to apply the `background-color` to. Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
        $('nav.navbar-custom').css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
    } else {
        $('nav.navbar-custom').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

Comment: For some reason when I tried this it didn't work as well.

Comment: Have you checked that the function is actually running and that the condition is being met as desired? You can debug with your browser's dev tools or use `console.log`

Comment: Hello, I tried using console.log and asked it to log a message when the document is being scrolled. I noticed that it isn't logging anything meaning there is something wrong. I don't know exactly what this is but could you help by taking a look at my GitHub. Thank You so much for the help.